# Receiving key_load_public error but ssh key executes correctly

Tags: ssh, encryption

Connecting to a remote using Cygwin. I have the following:

```
Remote: /home/myname/.ssh/authorized_keys
Local: /home/myname/bin/tempkey & /home/myname/bin/tempkey.pub
```

The `tempkey.pub` is altered to include the following before "ssh-rsa":

`command="pwd",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding`

Thus it reads:

`command="pwd",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-rsa ...[rest of key]`

The key pair are passphrase-free keys, hence the edit. When issued without `no-agent-forwarding` piece, I receive no error (same occurs if the keys had a passphrase). However, when I execute:

`ssh -i tempkey myname@server`

I receive:

```
key_load_public: invalid format
/home/myname
```

So the key is executing the command just fine. But I dont know what is invalid with the format.

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863913/key-load-public-invalid-format

Comment: ssh executes as your private key is fine, it is your public key that has a problem

Comment: @bodhi.zazen But the keys are cut from the same `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa`. All I did was edit the beginning of the public key, and copy its contents into the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Post the contents of your keys